# What are the benefits of chanting the names of Lord Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu

If possible please provide quotations.

Comment: Add question in the body. There is no question at all. See [ask].

Comment: Do you mean benefits in the real world (like any repeated chanting that brings peace) or examples from scriptures?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some quotes from Bhagavatam.

> SB 12.3.51: My dear King, although Kali-yuga is an ocean of faults,
>   there is still one good quality about this age: Simply by chanting the
>   names of Kṛṣṇa, **one can become free from material bondage** and be
>   promoted to the transcendental kingdom.
>
> SB 11.5.36: Those who are actually advanced in knowledge are able to
>   appreciate the essential value of this Age of Kali. Such enlightened
>   persons worship Kali-yuga because in this fallen age all **perfection of
>   life can easily be achieved** by the performance of saṅkīrtana.
>
> SB 11.5.37: Indeed, there is no higher possible gain for embodied
>   souls forced to wander throughout the material world than the Supreme
>   Lord’s saṅkīrtana movement, by which **one can attain the supreme peace
>   and free oneself from the cycle of repeated birth and death**.
>
> SB 2.1.11: O King, constant chanting of the holy name of the Lord
>   after the ways of the great authorities is the **doubtless and fearless
>   way of success for all, including those who are free from all material
>   desires, those who are desirous of all material enjoyment, and also
>   those who are self-satisfied** by dint of transcendental knowledge.
>
> SB 8.23.16: There may be discrepancies in pronouncing the mantras and
>   observing the regulative principles, and, moreover, there may be
>   discrepancies in regard to time, place, person and paraphernalia. **But
>   when Your Lordship’s holy name is chanted, everything becomes
>   faultless**.
>
> SB 1.1.14: Living beings who are entangled in the **complicated meshes
>   of birth and death can be freed** immediately by even unconsciously
>   chanting the holy name of Kṛṣṇa, which is feared by fear personified.
>
> SB 12.12.47: If when falling, slipping, feeling pain or sneezing one
>   involuntarily cries out in a loud voice, “Obeisances to Lord Hari!”
>   one **will be automatically freed from all his sinful reactions**.
>
> SB 12.3.44: Terrified, about to die, a man collapses on his bed.
>   Although his voice is faltering and he is hardly conscious of what he
>   is saying, if he utters the holy name of the Supreme Lord **he can be
>   freed from the reaction of his fruitive work and achieve the supreme
>   destination**. But still people in the Age of Kali will not worship the
>   Supreme Lord.
>
> SB 11.2.40: By chanting the holy name of the Supreme Lord, one comes
>   to the stage of love of Godhead. Then the devotee is fixed in his vow
>   as an eternal servant of the Lord, and he gradually becomes very much
>   attached to a particular name and form of the Supreme Personality of
>   Godhead. **As his heart melts with ecstatic love, he laughs very loudly
>   or cries or shouts. Sometimes he sings and dances like a madman, for
>   he is indifferent to public opinion**.
>
> SB 12.13.23: I offer my respectful obeisances unto the Supreme Lord,
>   Hari, **the congregational chanting of whose holy names destroys all
>   sinful reactions**, and the offering of obeisances unto whom relieves
>   all material suffering.

You can also refer this section of Bhagavatam, it has many such verses.
**[SB 6.2: Ajāmila Delivered by the Viṣṇudūtas](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/2)**

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://www.swami-krishnananda.org/vishnu/Sri_Vishnu.pdf) are the possible fruits one gains from reciting the names of Lord Vishnu. These verses are from the *Vishnu Sahasranama* (One thousand names of Vishnu):

> He who hears or sings, It all without fail, In all days of the year,
>   Will never get in to bad, In this life and after.
>
> The Brahmin will get knowledge, The kshatriya will get victory, The
>   vaisya will get wealth, The shudra will get pleasures, By reading
>   these.
>
> He who seeks Dharma, He who seeks wealth, He who seeks pleasures, He
>   who seeks children, Will all without fail, Get what they want.
>
> He who sings the thousand names of Vasudeva, With utmost devotion,
>   After he rises in the morn, With a mind tied in Him always, Will get
>   fame without fail, Will be first in what he does, Will get riches that
>   last, Would attain salvation from these bonds, Will never be afraid of
>   anything, Will be bubbling with vim and valour, Will not get any ills,
>   Will be handsome forever, Will have all the virtues in this wide
>   world, And he who is ill will get cured, He who is bound will be free,
>   He who is afraid, will get rid of fear, He who is in danger, will be
>   safe.
>
> He who chants these holy thousand names, With devotion to
>   Purushottama, Will cross the miseries, That cannot be crossed Without
>   fail.
>
> The man who nears Vasudeva, The man who takes Him as shelter, Would
>   get rid of all sins, And become purer than the pure, And will reach
>   Brahmam, Which existed forever.
>
> The devotees of Vasudeva the great, Never fall into days that are
>   difficult, And never forever suffer, Of birth, death, old age and
>   fear.
>
> He who sings these names with devotion, And with Bhakthi, Will get
>   pleasure the great, Patience to allure, Wealth to attract, Bravery and
>   memory to excel.
>
> The devotee of the Lord Purushottama, Has neither anger nor fear, Nor
>   avarice and nor bad thoughts.
>
> He who desires fame and pleasure, Should chant these verses, sung by
>   Vyasa, Of this great stotra of Vishnu without fail.
>
> He will never fail, Who sings the praise of the Lord, Of this
>   universe, Who does not have birth, Who is always stable, And who
>   shines and sparkles, And has lotus eyes. Om Nama He will not fail.

Answer (score 4):

As per **PADMA-PURANA: UTTARKHANDA: Chapter 232. The Raise of Goddess Laksmi:**

> Lord Shiva said:
>
> He who, being restrained, would devoutly mutter the three names of Visnu, viz. Acyuta, Ananta, Govinda, beginning with Pranava (i.e. Om) and (also) ending with Om, has no fear of death, so also the great fear due to poison, disease and fire. The wise, restrained one, who would mutter the great hymn—the three names—does not have fear of Death; then from where else (can he have it)? Thus with (the muttering of) the three names I drank that poison.

---

The benefits of chanting the names of Lord Vishnu are mentioned in many other places, for example:

- [PADMA-PURANA: UTTARAKHANDA: Chapter 72. **Merit of Reciting the Visnusahasranama**](https://archive.org/details/PadmaPuranaMotilalVol.3Thru10/page/n1723)
- [Mahabharata: Anusasana Parva: Section CXLIX (**Vishnu Sahasranama**)](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b114.htm)
- [PADMA-PURANA: BHUMIKHANDA: Chapter 87. A Hundred Names of Visnu or '**Vishnu Satanama**'](https://archive.org/details/PadmaPuranaMotilalVol.3Thru10/page/n335)
- [PADMA-PURANA: UTTARAKHANDA: Chapter 71. Visnu's One Thousand Names or '**Vishnu Sahasranama**'](https://archive.org/details/PadmaPuranaMotilalVol.3Thru10/page/n1697)